# IntelliJ IDEA disable reformat js, xml code

Tags: intellij-idea, reformatting

in our project. when commit. we have option:
-reformat code
-rearrange code
-optimize imports.
How can i disable this option for js and xml file? reformat and rearrange only java file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPD. It is possible since Intellij 2018.3. Please [see the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/reformat-and-rearrange-code.html#exclude_file_from_reformat) for details.

---

Old reply:

You can't. Reformat is either enabled or disabled, for all files in a commit. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-167112

As a workaround, you can commit files you don't want to be formatted separately. If you use Git, commit the second set with Amend, so there will still be one commit.

Comment: This answer is not correct anymore, see [izogfif's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58875873/1948612)

Answer (score 3):

You can exclude files with `*.js` and `*.xml` extensions from reformatting (permanently). [Check the relevant documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/reformat-and-rearrange-code.html#exclude_file_from_reformat).